# How can I automatically read emails and send the data via https POST

Tags: javascript, email, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, bots

I am trying to get information from an email address into a Google Firestore Database. I am limited to receiving this information via an email. (gmail)

What I need it to do:

Once I receive an email, automatically get the data from the message 'body' or an attached file. Then send that data via an HTTPS Post request to one of my Google Cloud Functions (to then add to firestore).

I have a basic understanding of cloud functions but I am not even sure where to start when it comes to email reading "bots" or APIs.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I hope this type of question is acceptable here.

Comment: In what language do you want to implement this, there are nearly for every langauge a imap/pop lib that can read/receive emails. And a http request is not hard to implement.

Comment: JavaScript if possible, would I need to run some server through google cloud or amazon?

Comment: You need a os where you can install and execute code. If google, amazon, azure, on premise or your raspberry at home, is up to you. For js i can recomend you node.js: `imap` & `mailparser` are your needed npm packages here.